# Understanding unix user

Tags: permissions, users

Basically I want to know if my understanding of unix users is correct.

**1)** A unix user is basically a different set of permissions on some set of files and directories in a filesystem. For example a user may own some set of files and directories and execute different kind of actions on those files (execute/read/write)

**2)** Unix groups also have permissions and if a particular user is assigned to a group then user's permissions are extended to group's permissions.

**3)** Every process is started on behalf of a particular user.

Are the statements above correct?

**4)** When I download and install an application a bunch of directories and files are created. Is a user also created to manage newly installed application?

**5)** When I login to a unix system as a normal user and run an app by double-clicking on it on behalf of what user the process will run?

**6)** When I start a unix system a bunch of process are also started. On behalf of what user are they started?

Comment: UNIX users and groups are _numbers_.  To these numbers there may be associated permissions to files, directories, processes, regions of memory, and to other, more obscure corners of the system.  These numbers may also have associated _names_ (via `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group`), but that's not mandatory.  There are further restrictions for such a user to be able to `login`.

Comment: To add to what @SatoKatsura said, it's worth noting that while the number does not need to have to be associated with a name, the name still has to be unique to the number (according to the standard), i.e.: it's assumed that for every name there is only exactly one number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes
2. Yes
3. Yes
4. It depends, complex program (database, tomcat like web server) do, smaller (gif generator) don't.
5. It depends, if no set user id, program will run as clicking user.
6. `root` mostly, some as `www` (if you have a web server), some as `bin`, `mail`.